# In the elastic beanstalk, I get the message 'Service: Amazon S3, Message: Forbidden'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, permission-denied

My eb is currently on the docker platform and will read the Dockerrun.aws.json file on s3.

There is no problem when deploying from the web console, but deploying in the cli environment with the following command fails with the **`Service: Amazon S3, Message: Forbidden`** event log.

```sh
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --region [REGION] --environment-name [ENVIRONMENT_NAME] --version-label [VERSION_LABEL]
```

Also CloudTrail does not have any error code.. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: It uses the security token or credentials of the user who is used to logged in console.aws.amaon.com and works but in the cli, I believe you're using a role used for beanstalk instances ? If so, it should have S3 permissions.

Comment: @JamesDean Thanks for comment. I thought so, I tried all the policies on s3`(s3: *)`, but the same error message was shown.